# How do I make search from dataset using select2 gem quicker in my rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are over 9000 values in my dataset that users can choose from through a select tag. I am using select2 gem so they can search through the dataset but the time to load after and before i input something in the form is a lot. How do I reduce this? I alrady have minimuminputlength as 2 and that is not working for some reason.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    minimumInputLength: 2
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});


</script>
<%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", class: 'input-1' %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", class: 'input-1' %>

<%= f.select :city, ['les Escaldes,Andorra,Escaldes-Engordany,3040051', 'Andorra la Vella,Andorra,Andorra la Vella,3041563', 'Umm al Qaywayn,United Arab Emirates,Umm al Qaywayn,290594'...], { :include_blank => 'City' }, :required => true, class: 'js-example-basic-single' %>

    <% if current_user.profile %>
        <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-default', class: 'bu' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-default', class: 'bu' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also how I do edit the font and font size of the contents of the sleect 2 select values. Editing the class, 'js-example-basic-single' does not work.

Edit: The suggestion below does not work either for me. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});


$('select').select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3
});


</script>
<%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", class: 'input-1' %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", class: 'input-1' %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'input-1'%>
<%= f.select :age, [13, 14, 15,16,17...], { :include_blank => 'Age' }, :required => true, class: 'input-1' %>
<%= f.select :gender, ['Male','Female', 'Other'], { :include_blank => 'Gender' }, :required => true, class: 'input-1' %>
<%= f.select :city, ['les Escaldes,Andorra,Escaldes-Engordany,3040051', 'Andorra la Vella,Andorra,Andorra la Vella,3041563', 'Umm al Qaywayn,United Arab Emirates,Umm al Qaywayn,290594'...],{ :include_blank => 'City' }, :required => true, class: 'js-example-basic-single' %>
<%= f.text_field :collegeemail, placeholder: "College Email (Leave Empty If You Do Not Have One)", class: 'input-1' %>
    <% if current_user.profile %>
        <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-default', class: 'bu' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-default', class: 'bu' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please provide the code of how you initiate `.select2()` exactly. The code you posted above has invalid JS syntax and won't execute at all. I believe you should have `ajax` prop to make it fetch remote data

Comment: Actually it works slowly right now. I am able to search through the dataset to filter my choices of cities.

Comment: Okay, but it’s hard to help if you don’t show how you do it exactly

Comment: Are those cities part of a model? Is there anyway to narrow it down? Like that select box is disabled until they maybe pick a state first from another select2 box? that would allow for smaller collections that could speed it up.

Comment: as @GProst has pointed out the JS is wrong. While I don't foresee this increasing the speed any, `minimumInputLength: 2` should be passed as an option to the `select2` function.  [Doc Example](https://select2.org/searching#minimum-search-term-length)

Comment: @GProst does my edit help?

Comment: @engineersmnky so what should I do to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you're putting all of the existing 9000+ cities from your db into the page. That's why it takes so long to open a select (it takes some time for user to download such page + it probably takes long to just open/render such select after the page is loaded).

You have to pass just a few options (cities in your case) on the page initially and fetch the rest using AJAX, see [this instruction](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) in the `select2` docs.

You will need to implement an API endpoint in your Rails app to be able to fetch cities via AJAX request.